# Proof on the exterior measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set and let $\delta > 0$. Show that $m^*(\delta E)=\delta^n m^*(E)$, where $m^*$ is the exterior measure (outer measure).

Attempted proof:

Let $\{Q_j : j \in \mathcal{A}\}$ be a countable covering of $E$, where $Q_j$ are cubes in dimension $n$. This implies (?) that $\{\delta Q_j : j \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a countable covering of $\delta E$. Thus, $$m^*(\delta E) = \inf_j \sum_{j=1}^\infty |\delta Q_j| = \delta^n \inf_j \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j| = \delta^nm^*(E).$$

Questions:

1) How did my proof go? Is it missing anything, or is something fallacious?

2) If my proof is correct, then can anyone explain why (hence my inclusion of (?) in my proof) the statement "$\{Q_j : j \in \mathcal{A}\}$" holds if and only if the statement "$\{\delta Q_j : j \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a countable covering of $\delta E$" holds?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful when dealing with $\inf$. Indeed you have only one inequality for the moment:

For for open cover of $\{Q_i\}$ of $E$, 
$$ \delta^n \sum_{i=1}^\infty m(Q_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty m(\delta Q_i)\ge  m^*(\delta E)$$

So $\delta ^nm^*(E)\ge m^*(\delta E)$ when you take infimum over all $\{Q_i\}$. To do the other inequality, find an open cover $\{\tilde Q_i\}$ of $\delta E$, then....